# How to check if at least one element of a list is included in a text column?

Tags: pyspark

I have a data frame with a column containing text and a list of keywords. My goal is to build a new column showing if the text column contains at least one of the keywords. Let's look at some mock data:

```
test_data = [('1', 'i like stackoverflow'),
             ('2', 'tomorrow the sun will shine')]
test_df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(test_data).toDF(['id', 'text'])
```

With a single keyword ("sun") the solution would be:

```
test_df.withColumn(
    'text_contains_keyword', F.array_contains(F.split(test_df.text, ' '), 'sun')
).show()
```

[image]

The word "sun" is included in the second row of the `text` column, but not in the first. Now, let's say I have a list of keywords:

```
test_keywords = ['sun', 'foo', 'bar']
```

How to check for each of the words in `test_keywords` if they are included in the `text` column? Unfortunately, if I simply replace "sun" with the list, it leads to this error:

`Unsupported literal type class java.util.ArrayList [sun, foo, bar]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using the built in `rlike` function with the following code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

test_df = (test_df.withColumn("text_contains_word", 
                                functions.col('text')
                                 .rlike('(^|\s)(' + '|'.join(test_keywords) 
                                                    + ')(\s|$)')))

test_df.show()
+---+--------------------+------------------+
| id|                text|text_contains_word|
+---+--------------------+------------------+
|  1|i like stackoverflow|             false|
|  2|tomorrow the sun ...|              true|
+---+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: It works as expected; now, I will try to understand why ;-).

Comment: `'(^|\\s)(sun|foo|bar)(\\s|$)'` is the full regex expression. It checks if the string contains any of the words, and makes sure it is not part of another word. ie. words such as`food`,`barista`,`sunflower` will not be matched.